# Getting related values in Excel 2007

Tags: excel

In column B I have a football team name. In columns C, D, E I have some number values related to that team. My question is - Is it possible to type the name of the team in some random cell (let's say J4) and to automatically get the number values related to that team in cells J5, J6 and J7?

Comment: If your team information is in a table somewhere as described, you can use `VLOOKUP`. *E.g.*, `=VLOOKUP(J4, $B$1:$E$24, 2, FALSE)` will match `J4` entry to to the table defined in `$B$1` to `$E$24` and return the value from column `C` corresponding to `J4`. See [How to use Excel's VLOOKUP function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm).

Comment: Did you find anything here useful? You did not post ant feedback,

Answer (score 0):

If the worksheet is Sheet1, paste the following code in module Sheet1 of the VBE

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim teams As Range
    Set teams = Me.Range("B:B")
    Dim team As Range
    Set team = teams.Find(Target.Value, teams.Cells(1), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If (Not (team Is Nothing)) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = team.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Target.Offset(2, 0).Value = team.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Target.Offset(3, 0).Value = team.Offset(0, 3).Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(J$4,B:E,ROW()-3,0)
```

in J5 copied down to J7.